# SO discriminating against senior citizens

Tags: discussion

SO has been found to discriminate against our elder users (who are in their second-childishness). In About me section :

[image]

It is discriminating against children too :

[image]

Our elders and children users should have the right to own an account here I guess.

Comment: Not sure about "elders", but children, no. There is a minimum age of 13 for SO.

Comment: @Clive Ok but what about senior citizens ..

Comment: If a 95 year old wants to ask/answer a question, let 'em :)

Comment: I believe there are dupes on MSE about this... (posting from the app, hard to find the post)

Comment: @ThePragmatick Because this same exact question has already been been asked and answered. It was fairly popular too, and asked in basically the same wording as yours.

Comment: Oh its a duplicate. I didn't search properly. Thanks for posting @slugster Please vote to close this question.

Comment: Pretty sure they want a later birthdate to feel younger

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It is discriminating against children

Yes, SE is *required* to do so.  Mandated by COPPA, the Child Online Privacy Protection Act, a law in the USA that forbids any web site owner from gathering any information about a child under 13 years of age.  Like the kind of info you can find back in your profile.  Accordingly, this check is required to prevent children from creating accounts on SE sites.

> SO has been found to discriminate against our elder users

Age discrimination is a very real problem for a programmer.  Everybody considers you over-the-hill by the time you are thirty-something with the presumption that you haven't kept up with the rapid changes in software engineering practices.  Employers always look for somebody with 3-to-6 years of experience, it is rare to see 10 years as a job requirement, you might as well be dead and buried if you have 20 years.  This strongly motivates programmers to withhold or lie about their age.  And they have done so profusely in this SE dialog.  The old-age check was added to catch both children and older programmers typing nonsense intentionally.

Comment: Oh ok. Well, honestly, I don't think there are many 95+ aged people who'd like to create an account here.

Comment: Well, sonny, i'd tell you that in all my 96 years i've never heard a little bit of baloney like that. (jk)